# Stata: check if any variables follow a naming pattern

Tags: stata

I am about to create several temporary variables following the pattern `tmp_*`, and will `drop` (delete) them afterwards. I thought I would be clever and do...

```
ds tmp_*
assert ": word 1 of `r(varlist)'" == ""

** then I create and do stuff with tmp_bah and tmp_blah

drop tmp_*
```

That is, I wanted to perform a preliminary check to ensure that my final step does no damage to preexisting variables like `tmp_thing_i_forgot_about`.

Unsurprisingly, Stata did not oblige. The designers think my `ds tmp_*` is an error because it returns an empty result. I see that `ds` has several options, but none of them make it act like a normal search on the list of variable names (which would not whine upon a failed search).

I'm hoping someone can help me find the idiomatic way of approaching this problem.

Comment: See also `help capture`.

Comment: As a side note, your `assert` statement will likely not check what you want. I've included some code that illustrates in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but I think you can use `tempvar`s. A silly example:

```
clear 
set more off

sysuse auto
keep foreign

tempvar temp1

gen `temp1' = foreign - 100
gen usestemp = `temp1'^2
```

`tempvar` will fetch a safe name for your temporary variable and put it in `local temp1` (in my example). Use it as you wish and after the program finishes, Stata takes care of dropping it.

You can create several at once: `tempvar myvar1 myvar2 myvar3`.

See `help tempvar`; and details in **[P]** macro.

### Edit

As a side note, your `assert` statement will likely not check what you want. Consider some examples:

```
clear
set more off

set obs 1

gen tmp_1 = .
gen tmp_2 = .

ds tmp_*

* other versions
assert "`:word 1 of r(varlist)'" == "r(varlist)" // true
assert `:word 1 of r(varlist)' == "tmp_1 tmp_2"  // true
assert "`:word 1 of `=r(varlist)''" == "tmp_1"   // true

* your versions
assert ": word 1 of `r(varlist)'" == ": word 1 of tmp_1 tmp_2"  // true -->
assert ": word 1 of `r(varlist)'" == ""                         // ALWAYS false
```

I still find quotes a bit confusing, so I check very carefully when I have to use them; just to make sure the expression evaluates to what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. As the purpose of `ds` is to display variable names, it's considered an error if what you specify isn't a *varlist*. You could

```
 capture ds tmp_*
```

and work conditionally on the error code. But I wouldn't do that.

First of all, it's a purpose of `confirm` to confirm whether something exists. That's much more direct.

Second, it's fine to try to `generate` a new variable but to be clear that this will produce an error if that exists.

Third, far and away the best method to create a new temporary variable is to use the `tempvar` mechanism of getting a new name and then follow that with `generate`. As @Roberto Ferrer has separately explained that, all I need to do is to underline that it's the way to go.

EDIT: `ds` has morphed in its history from a command whose original purpose was a very concise display of variable names to one whose main role is to find names of variables defined by some criterion (e.g. being string or having value labels or a date format): `findname` (*Stata Journal*/SSC) is in essence a further generalization of `ds` that makes that more explicit. Note that a simple `describe` will return `r(111)` if the names specified are not in use and that's a further direct test that can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the broader perspective, Nick. The problem wasn't `generate` but rather that I wanted to `drop tmp_*` later without capturing anything extra (like some other variable with the same prefix that I'd forgotten about). I'll accept Roberto's answer because it solves that underlying problem. Maybe I ought to change the question title, though...dunno.